# Specific media queries extract and store in a variable

Tags: javascript, gulp, html-email

I'm using Gulp as an email generator. This generator uses Juice to manipulate a CSS file linked to the HTML file and will inline, clean, keep media queries in the head, etc. to have a final HTML file without a CSS file linked to it.

The issue I have is with dark mode. In the email, we are using the "normal" dark mode media query (`@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)`) but also other declarations for specific mailing platforms such as Outlook.

This specific declaration is in a `<style>` tag:

```
[data-ogsc] body { background-color: #2a2c2e !important; }
[data-ogsb] body { background-color: #2a2c2e !important; }
```

But, even though those are in my CSS file, Juice is stripping it.

Here is my task that does most of the job:

```
// tasks/juice.js
"use strict";


module.exports = function(gulp, $, fromRoot) {

    var juice = require('gulp-juice-concat');
    var removeUnused = require("gulp-email-remove-unused-css");

    gulp.task("juice", function(done) {
        gulp
            .src(fromRoot("dist") + "/*.html")
            .pipe(
                juice({
                    applyStyleTags: true,
                    applyLinkTags: true,
                    removeStyleTags: true,
                    preservePseudos: true,
                    preserveMediaQueries: true,
                    applyAttributesTableElements: true,
                    preserveImportant: true,
                    preserveFontFaces: true,
                    applyWidthAttributes: true
                })
            )
            .pipe(
                removeUnused({
                    whitelist: [
                        ".External*",
                        ".ReadMsgBody",
                        ".yshortcuts",
                        ".Mso*",
                        "#outlook",
                        "#preheader",
                        "#MessageViewBody",
                        "#body",
                        "u",
                        "[data-ogsc]",
                        "[data-ogsb]"
                    ],
                })
            )
    .pipe(gulp.dest(fromRoot("dist")));
    done();
    });

};
```

The idea I have in mind is to add a supplemental task to my `npm run dist` (after the juice) that will extract the content of `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)`, add relevant value, and reinject that in the HTML file.

But I have not found any solution so far to do that.

My gulpfile.js looks like this at the moment:

```
// gulpfile.js
'use strict';

const
    gulp = require('gulp'),
      fromRoot = require('../utils/from-root'),

      $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({
        pattern: '*',
        config: '../../package.json',
        scope: ['dependencies', 'devDependencies', 'peerDependencies'],
        rename: {
          'lodash.assign': 'assign'
        }
      });


$.loadSubtasks('./tasks/**/*.js', $, fromRoot);

gulp.task('dist', gulp.series('clean:dist', 'sass:dist', 'src:dist', 'juice'));
```

Answer (score -2):

Try like this:

```
'use strict';

const gulp = require('gulp');
const fromRoot = require('../utils/from-root');
const $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({
    pattern: '*',
    config: '../../package.json',
    scope: ['dependencies', 'devDependencies', 'peerDependencies'],
    rename: {
        'lodash.assign': 'assign'
    }
});

$.loadSubtasks('./tasks/**/*.js', $, fromRoot);

gulp.task('dist', gulp.series('clean:dist', 'sass:dist', 'src:dist', 'juice', 'extract-dark-mode-css'));

gulp.task('extract-dark-mode-css', function(done) {
    const cheerio = require('cheerio');
    const fs = require('fs');

    // Define a function to extract and manipulate CSS inside @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)
    function extractAndManipulateDarkModeCSS(filePath) {
        const html = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);

        // Extract and manipulate the CSS within the media query
        $('style').each(function() {
            const styleContent = $(this).html();
            if (styleContent.includes('@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)')) {
                // Modify the CSS content as needed
                const modifiedCSS = styleContent.replace(/body\s*{/g, '[data-ogsc] body, [data-ogsb] body {');
                // Replace the original CSS with the modified version
                $(this).html(modifiedCSS);
            }
        });

        // Save the modified HTML back to the file
        fs.writeFileSync(filePath, $.html(), 'utf8');
    }

    // Process all HTML files in the 'dist' directory
    gulp.src(fromRoot('dist') + '/*.html')
        .on('data', (file) => {
            extractAndManipulateDarkModeCSS(file.path);
        })
        .on('end', done);
});
```

Comment: A "solution" with only code and no explanation describing what was wrong with the original code and how/why your solution fixes the problem is not very useful.

Comment: sorry I'm new. In this code, I added a new Gulp task called 'extract-dark-mode-css', which reads all the HTML files in the 'dist' directory, extracts and modifies the CSS inside @media (prefers-color- scheme: dark) and then overwrites the HTML files with the modified CSS.

Comment: Thanks for your proposition, i'll have a look. 

One thing i forgot to mention, the generator is a generator, so not only the body can have a specific color in dark-mode, but also lot of other css classes. And i cannot anticipate their naming since it is used by other email-developers. 

So limit that only to the body is a problem to me. I would need to have each css class to have this `[data-ogsc/b]` added to it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).